# Form1 is a type but used like a variable

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a problem accessing my ListBox1 inside a class.

```
public static void LoadLists(Form1 f1)
       {
           string path = "//Employees.meta";
           var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
           var items = doc.Descendants("Employees");
           var query = from x in items

                       select new
                       {
                           Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                           Gender = (string)x.Element("SubData")
                               .Element("Person")
                               .Element("Gender")
                       };

           foreach (var item in query)
           {
               f1.listBox1.Items.Add(item.Name);
           }
      }
```

This compiles fine, but inside the API when using LoadLists(Form1 f1) it shows error 
Form1 is a type but used like a variable

Help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: how are you calling this method?

Comment: I worked this out roughly 5min after asking  -                private static  Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code does not produce the error.

The code that *uses* the method presumably looks like `LoadLists(Form1)` or `LoadLists(Form1 form)` both of which are invalid as `Form1` is not a variable in the *using* scope - as indicated by the error message.